# Vue: emitting from a child with data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have always passed data accompanying an emitted function in an object but is it bad practive to do it with just consecutive arguments?  I have my event, `clickMe`, then a string `activeName` and then 2 properties from the `v-for`.

```js
<Child v-for="x in notifications" :key="x.name">
  <a
    @click="$emit('clickMe', 'activeName', x.name, x.isEnabled)"
  >
</Child>
```

Comment: no, but why when you can just pass the whole object and only collect them from the parent. e.g. `$emit('clickMe', 'activeName', x)` and `@activeName="func"` and `func({ name, isEnabled }) {}`

Answer (score 1):

Passing several arguments to a function can be a bad practice (more here: https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/clean-code-javascript#function-arguments-2-or-fewer-ideally)

You should be able to do just:

```
$emit('clickMe', { activeName: 'activeName', name: x.name, enabled: x.enabled})
```

Then, from the recipient parent just destruct the second argument.